# Nativescript: Make label span width of its content, then wrap at a max width

Tags: ios, label, nativescript

I am trying to create a messaging view with a layout similar to iMessage, where a chat "bubble" is the size of its content, until it gets to be a certain width. Like this:
[image: screenshot]

With nativescript, I cant find a layout that will accommodate this. I tried using GridLayout, but the auto nature of the column appears to mean that it will be the size of the content, even if the content's size expands beyond the view.

```
<GridLayout width="100%" columns="40, auto" rows="auto, 20" class="msg them" visibility="{{is_me ? 'collapsed' : 'visible'}}">
    <Image class="authorimg" col="0" stretch="aspectFill" verticalAlignment="top" src="{{user.profile_photo ? user.profile_photo.sizes.tiny_square : ''}}" />
    <StackLayout class="msg_text" col="1">
        <Label text="{{message}}" textWrap="true" verticalAlignment="top" />
    </StackLayout>
    <Label class="msg_timestamp" text="{{author}}" verticalAlignment="top" row="1" colSpan="2" />
</GridLayout>
```

That produces this:
[image: screenshot]

Notice the longer ones dont wrap, despite textWrap=true on the Label.

The other side of the coin is this:

```
<GridLayout width="100%" columns="40, *" rows="auto, 20" class="msg them" visibility="{{is_me ? 'collapsed' : 'visible'}}">
    <Image class="authorimg" col="0" stretch="aspectFill" verticalAlignment="top" src="{{user.profile_photo ? user.profile_photo.sizes.tiny_square : ''}}" />
    <StackLayout class="msg_text" col="1">
        <Label text="{{message}}" textWrap="true" verticalAlignment="top" />
    </StackLayout>
    <Label class="msg_timestamp" text="{{author}}" verticalAlignment="top" row="1" colSpan="2" />
</GridLayout>
```

The only difference being the columns in the gridlayout, in this case its set to * (use the rest of the available area). That however, produces this:

[image: screenshot]

Notice that the shorter messages span the whole width. I need something similar to width="auto" on the Label I guess. I cant figure out a layout that will accommodate the best of both implementations, small bubbles for little text, and wrapping bubbles for long text.

Comment: Hey, have you try to create another column in your gridLayout ?
Something like columns="40, *, *"

Comment: @Kansen I did try that! Using * for the second column (the column with the message Label) makes the Label span the whole width of the column. And adding another in there just divides the remaining space between those two columns, producing this: https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/2E1S2k0C3S2t1s233T3j/Screenshot%202016-08-31%2008.42.59.png?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=196928

Answer (score 12):

using StackLayout will do the job:

```
<StackLayout>
  <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" style="padding: 5">
    <Image src="~/res/logo.png" width="50" height="50" verticalAlignment="top"/>
    <Label text="I am a message" textWrap="true" backgroundColor="red" />
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" style="padding: 5">
    <Image src="~/res/logo.png" width="50" height="50" verticalAlignment="top"/>
    <Label text="This is a longer message, which is worth adding because then I can make sure that longer messages display properly in the messages view! They need to wrap, obviously!" backgroundColor="red" textWrap="true" />
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

You should have in mind that layouts are not virtualized. This will make your app slow when there are large conversations. You can use list view instead.

Comment: THANK YOU! This finally worked. Btw, this is embedded in a list view. I will detail exactly how it was accomplished in an update, I upvoted your response.

Answer (score 7):

Try wrapping the StackLayout in a Grid. A StackLayout measures one of it's sides to infinity (in Veritcal orientation, the width is infinite. In Horizontal orientation, the height is infinite).

In your configuration, the right boundary is measured to infinity, therefore the Label has no place to wrap.

```
<GridLayout width="100%" columns="40, *" rows="auto, 20" class="msg them" visibility="{{is_me ? 'collapsed' : 'visible'}}">
<Image class="authorimg" col="0" stretch="aspectFill" verticalAlignment="top" src="{{user.profile_photo ? user.profile_photo.sizes.tiny_square : ''}}" />
<GridLayout col="1">
<StackLayout class="msg_text" >
    <TextView editable="false"  text="{{message}}" textWrap="true" verticalAlignment="top" />
</StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

To address your second concern about keeping the smaller messages left aligned, you set the StackLayout to be left aligned within the new GridLayout. This should produce the result where only long messages will fill the space presented by the second columns's GridLayout.

Here's a rudimentary illustration:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with the following code

```
<GridLayout width="100%" columns="40, *" rows="auto, 20" class="msg them" visibility="{{is_me ? 'collapsed' : 'visible'}}">
<Image class="authorimg" col="0" stretch="aspectFill" verticalAlignment="top" src="{{user.profile_photo ? user.profile_photo.sizes.tiny_square : ''}}" />
<StackLayout class="msg_text" col="1">
    <Textview editable="false"  text="{{message}}" textWrap="true" verticalAlignment="top" />
</StackLayout>
<Label class="msg_timestamp" text="{{author}}" verticalAlignment="top" row="1" colSpan="2" />
```

The thing is that **Label** tag is for one line display while **Textview** allows you a several line display.

I hope this helped you,
Cheers

Comment: This doesnt work. TextView spans the whole length of the column, and when the column is *, its the remainder of the view. Also, Label is not just for one line display, textWrap="true" property lets a label span multiple lines. Using TextView instead of Label results in this: https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/3F0w140i2f0J2Y0R1K3G/Screenshot%202016-08-31%2011.46.45.png?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=196928

Comment: Then i'll try my last bullet :
If your colums are set as follow : columns = "40,auto,*"
First columns set to 40 for your picture
Second columns with auto like that the column will get the width of your child component (label/textview)
Third column as a star to fill the remaining space

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesnt work. The auto column is not constrained to the view, it sizes to the content, not letting the Label wrap.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest shortcut to get this done would be to give a margin of desired result (such as 30%) to the opposite side. So then without adding any much complicated layouts this can be got done.

```
<FlexboxLayout 
class="response-right">
  <Label text="Hi" textWrap="true"></Label>
  <Label text="05:00 AM" class="time" textWrap="true"></Label>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

CSS would be :

```
.response-right{
background-color: white;
align-self: flex-end;
padding: 5;
margin: 10 5 10 30%;
flex-direction: column;
border-radius: 10;
.time{
    text-align: right;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}}
```